# jQuery resize event gets called many times while resizing process goes on

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, slider

`SettingsSlider` resize event can happen hundreds of times just for a small change in size and I'm don't know how to make it right.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzTna/

```
horizontalslider: function (){

        var startnum = 0,
        mySlider, mySlider2, mySlider3, mySlider4, mySlider5, mySlider6, mySlider7, mySlider8, settings1 = {


        }, settings2 = {

        };

        function settings() {
            return ($(window).width() < 800) ? settings1 : settings2;
        }

        mySlider2 = $('.one').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider3 = $('.two').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider4 = $('.three').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider5 = $('.four').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider6 = $('.five').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider7 = $('.six').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider8 = $('.seven').bxSlider(settings());
        mySlider = $('.eight').bxSlider(settings());

        function SettingsSlider() {
            mySlider.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider2.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider2.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider3.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider3.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider4.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider4.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider5.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider5.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider6.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider6.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider7.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider7.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
            mySlider8.reloadSlider($.extend(settings(), {
                startSlide: mySlider8.getCurrentSlide()
            }));
        }
        $(window).resize(SettingsSlider);

},
```

Comment: Paul Irish makes it: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: @A. Wolff would u be able to amend my fiddle with this solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes resize event call several times until you stop resizing your browser. To prevent is & call it only once you can use clearTimeOut() methon in javascript.

```
var timer;
$(window).resize(function(e){

    clearTimeOut(timer);
    timer = setTimeOut(your_method(),100);

});

function your_method(){
    // Your Code
}
```

change your SettingsSlider method to

```
function SettingsSlider() {
                mySlider.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider2.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider3.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider4.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider5.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider6.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider7.reloadSlider(settings());
                mySlider8.reloadSlider(settings());
            }
```

Comment: @sanguisuga I think it is working now. I only works when you stopped resizing.. right?

Comment: @rohanAM unfortunately  this function makes firefox crashing. I dunno what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @sanguisuga it's cause window.onresize does not works in Firefox. Use $(window).resize() method of jQuery instead as shown in my answer.

Comment: @rohanAM what is the solution?

Comment: @sanguisuga ckeck my answer, use $(window).resize() method of jQuery

Comment: @rohanAM as I said, it still crashing with browser Firefox. not sure why

Comment: @sanguisuga it should be `setTimeout(your_method,100);` not `setTimeOut(your_method(),100);` which is wrong here

Comment: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://localhost:8080/assets/js/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2

Comment: @sanguisuga It reloadSlider() method of bxSlider which is causing problem, you were passing two sets of options to reloadSlider() method, I've updated it in jsFiddle. check here http://jsfiddle.net/bzTna/8/ now it works fine on Firefox

Comment: @rohanAM thanks for this but still crashes. My browser won't load at all.